# Fonts too bold after recent MathJax upgrade?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, math-display

This is not an actual bug, so I am tagging it as a feature-request, but after MathJax upgrade, all the fonts look more bold for me, as if too much antialiasing were applied. This happens both in Chrome 10 and Firefox 4 on Mac OS X 10.6.6. Can anybody confirm this, or is it just me? Should I empty some cache or there are some settings to tweak?

Here is the example:
[image]

The problem or a feature is that the mathematical text is too bold compared to normal text. This a new behaviour which was nor present before.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome 10 on Windows 7 I see this

[Estimating noise correlation in augmented state vector Kalman filter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8942/estimating-noise-correlation-in-augmented-state-vector-kalman-filter)

[image]

So is this Mac specific?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to right click on a formula and click about for MathJax and paste in the results?

It should look something like:

```
MathJax v1.1
using TeX web fonts

TeX Input Jax v1.1
HTML-CSS Output Jax v1.1
mml Element Jax v1.1
tex2jax Extension v1.1
MathZoom Extension v1.1
MathMenu Extension v1.1
TeX/noErrors Extension v1.0.1
TeX/noUndefined Extension v1.0.1
Firefox v3.6.16 — otf fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my output:

```
TeX Input Jax v1.1
HTML-CSS Output Jax v1.1
mml Element Jax v1.1
tex2jax Extension v1.1
MathZoom Extension v1.1
MathMenu Extension v1.1
TeX/noErrors Extension v1.0.1
TeX/noUndefined Extension v1.0.1
Chrome v10.0.648.204 — otf fonts
```

Since this seems Mac OS X specific, maybe it is some antialiasing issue. I've already got used to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Font rendering looks fine to me. Anyway, for the record, here is mine with Safari (OS X):

```
MathJax v1.1
using TeX web fonts

TeX Input Jax v1.1
HTML-CSS Output Jax v1.1
mml Element Jax v1.1
tex2jax Extension v1.1
MathZoom Extension v1.1
MathMenu Extension v1.1
TeX/noErrors Extension v1.0.1
TeX/noUndefined Extension v1.0.1
Safari v5.0.4 — otf fonts
```